# Spinner dropdown not resizing

Tags: android, mobile

I have been working on an app for a schoolproject (First time making an app and school doesn't help me with it).
I wanted to add a spinner to display multiple group names and decided I needed a custom adapter for it so I made one but now I am not able to resize the dialog result.

Here is the code I am using:
Custom adapter

```
public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Group> {
public int _layout;
public int _dropdown;

public GroupAdapter(Context context, int resource, int dropdown, List<Group> object){
    super(context, resource, object);
    _dropdown = dropdown;
    _layout = resource;
}

public GroupAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Group> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GroupHolder mainViewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(_dropdown, parent, false);
        GroupHolder groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
        groupHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_groupName);
        convertView.setTag(groupHolder);
    }

    convertView.setMinimumWidth(100);
    mainViewHolder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();

    Group group = getItem(position);
    mainViewHolder.textView.setText(group.Name);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(_layout, parent, false);

    TextView header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_headGroupName);
    header.setText(getItem(position).Name);

    return view;
}
```

Layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView_headGroupName"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Dropdown layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView_groupName"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
Declaring spinner:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_groups);
GroupAdapter spinnerAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_header_spinner, R.layout.activity_listitem_groupitem, lockManager.Groups);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

I hope someone is able to help me with this. I hope I am not asking anything stupid here.

Thanks in advance,
Patrick de Mooij

Comment: Please show how the spinner itself is being declared.

Comment: @TedHopp added that to the post.

Comment: No, I meant the XML that declares the spinner. What attributes does the `<Spinner>` tag have?

Comment: @TedHopp It has a width, height, id, style and spinnermode. That's all.

Comment: I guess I should have asked earlier: what do you mean that you are "not able to resize the dialog result". What dialog? (Also, in your code, you are using a hard-coded 100 for the minimum width; you should be using something like `(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics())`.)